# how to enlist multiple records filtered by checkedlistbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, checkedlistbox

i have a data grid view  and checked list box. checked list box is populated from database items i want create  filter using checked list box's items means to populate data grid view by checking checked list box's items now the problem is that data grid view show only only one record corresponds to checked item but does not display multiple records if multiple checkbox items are checked.

[image]

```
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-50ME4GC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=autolab;Integrated Security=True";
        if (pn.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            // If so, loop through all checked items and print results.  
            string s = "";
            int x;
            for (x = 0; x <= pn.CheckedItems.Count - 1; x++)
            {
                s = s + pn.CheckedItems[x].ToString();
            }
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT *  from test_report  inner join tests  on test_report.test_name = tests.Test_name WHERE tests.Test_name IN ('" + s + "') ", connection);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);


            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();


           adapter.Fill(tbl);


            dt.DataSource = tbl;


            connection.Close();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your string with the item names is composed incorrectly, suppose you have those elements:

```
One
Two
Three
```

Your concat would do this:

```
OneTwoThree
```

While you want:

```
'One','Two','Three'
```

So you need to correct the concat like this:

```
        string s = "";
        int x;
        for (x = 0; x <= pn.CheckedItems.Count - 1; x++)
        {
            s = s + "'" + pn.CheckedItems[x].ToString() + "',";
        }

        s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1);
```

And correct the query to be this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT *  from test_report  inner join tests  on test_report.test_name = tests.Test_name WHERE tests.Test_name IN (" + s + ") ", connection);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your for loop concatenates list items. Try to write

```
s = s + pn.CheckedItems[x].ToString() + ", ";
```

Do not forget to remove last ", " after the loop.